# Powershell - Split, add and connect string

Tags: string, powershell, split

I have something like that:

```
$s1 = 4859p_so-me-ot-he-rt-e-xt
$s1= $s1.split("-"); $s1= $s1[0]
```

I get result:

```
4859p
```

And I also have string 2

```
$s2 = abrakada_12.10.10.200_split_ASD_DE_BD_91_ABRA_TEXT_TEXT
```

And how i can split s2 to make result like that:

```
abrakada_12.10.10.200_split-4859p_ASD_DE_BD_91_ABRA_TEXT_TEXT
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try replace to achieve this:

```
$s2=$s2 -replace "split",("split-"+$s1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was so simple :)

Answer (score -1):

May be u can split the second string as well and then concatenate/join it.
$s3= $s1 -split "_"

$s4= $s4 -split "split"

$s5=[string]::join("split_"+$s3[0],$s4)